# Can't seem to append text for my richtextbox on Twitter start stream method C#

Tags: c#, twitter

the problem I am facing is that i cant seem to get the following code working...

```
SimpleStream stream = new SimpleStream("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json");
stream.StreamStarted += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Stream has started!");
// Starting the stream by specifying credentials thanks to the Token
//stream.AddTrack("usa");
stream.StartStream(token, x => richTextBox1.AppendText(x.Text));
```

The error that I get is "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

richTextBox is part of my form cs file and I tried changing it to static in the Designer.cs file it compiles however nothing happens on AppendText method

Comment: This code is inside a console application, and u want to use a richTextBox from a form ... ? Give more details please

Comment: It's in a form class, I want a new tweet to be put there instead of the console

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you're trying to access an instance member of your class (presumably richTextBox1) from a static method\property. You need to change the method to be non-static (so it has access to the local instance members).

If this doesn't help, you will need post the details of your class\method.